# python pandas split datafram column into two new column and drop the original column

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Steve Smith', 'Joe Nadal',
                            'Roger Federer'],
                  'birthdat/company': ['1995-01-26Sharp, Reed and Crane',
                                      '1955-08-14Price and Sons',
                                      '2000-06-28Pruitt, Bush and Mcguir']})

df[['data_time','full_company_name']] = df['birthdat/company'].str.split('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', expand=True)
df
```

with my code I get the following:

```
____|____Name______|__birthdat/company_______________|_birthdate_|____company___________
0   |Steve Smith   |1995-01-26Sharp, Reed and Crane  |           |Sharp, Reed and Crane
1   |Joe Nadal     |1955-08-14Price and Sons         |           |Price and Sons
2   |Roger Federer |2000-06-28Pruitt, Bush and Mcguir|           |Pruitt, Bush and Mcguir
```

what I want is - get this regex ('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}') and the rest should go to the column "full_company_name" and :

```
____|____Name______|_birthdate_|____company_name_______
0   |Steve Smith   |1995-01-26 |Sharp, Reed and Crane
1   |Joe Nadal     |1955-08-14 |Price and Sons
2   |Roger Federer |2000-06-28 |Pruitt, Bush and Mcguir
```

Updated Question:
How could I handle missing values for birthdate or company name,
example: birthdate/company = "NaApple" or birthdate/company = "2003-01-15Na" the missing values are not only limited to Na

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```py
df[['data_time','full_company_name']] = df['birthdat/company'].str.extract(r'^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})(.*)', expand=False)
>>> df
            Name  Age  ...   data_time        full_company_name
0    Steve Smith   32  ...  1995-01-26    Sharp, Reed and Crane
1      Joe Nadal   34  ...  1955-08-14           Price and Sons
2  Roger Federer   36  ...  2000-06-28  Pruitt, Bush and Mcguir

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

The [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) is used here because you need to get two parts without losing the date.

The regex is

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})` - your date pattern captured into Group 1
- `(.*)` - the rest of the string captured into Group 2.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/HvnZ47/1).

Answer (score 1):

`split` splits the string by the separator while ignoring them. I think you want `extract` with two capture groups:

```
df[['data_time','full_company_name']] = \
   df['birthdat/company'].str.extract('^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})(.*)')
```

Output:

```
    Name           birthdat/company                   data_time    full_company_name
--  -------------  ---------------------------------  -----------  -----------------------
 0  Steve Smith    1995-01-26Sharp, Reed and Crane    1995-01-26   Sharp, Reed and Crane
 1  Joe Nadal      1955-08-14Price and Sons           1955-08-14   Price and Sons
 2  Roger Federer  2000-06-28Pruitt, Bush and Mcguir  2000-06-28   Pruitt, Bush and Mcguir
```

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of the other answer?

Comment: @RyszardCzech Not to be picky, but according to timestamp, mine is the same with the other answer. Why mine is automatically a duplicate?

Comment: Well, the timestamps are not the same, I see a minute difference.

Comment: @RyszardCzech OK, now I see one minute. That said, the time difference is less than one minute. That was just time to copy/paste the answer. When I posted my answer, I certainly didn't see the other answer although it could have been on the system. That's not to mention editing/re-editing not showing up after the answer was posted, and my  answer explicitly explains the `split` behavior. I don't think downvoting my answer because of that is fair.